# Unexpected results from boost::lexical_cast<int> with boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, boost

I tried converting a substring (expressed by a pair of iterators) to an integer by `boost::lexical_cast`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    // assume [first, last) as substring
    const std::string s("80");
    auto first = s.begin(), last = s.end();

    std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<int>(boost::make_iterator_range(first, last)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: ([wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gRpKVWyeRCQQUAF4))

```
1
```

I got expected result (80) by workaround: `boost::make_iterator_range(&*first, last - first)`.

**Question**: **Why** above code does not work as expected? And, where does `1` come from?

1. `lexical_cast` does not support `iterator_range<std::string::(const_)iterator>`
2. misuse of `lexical_cast` or `iterator_range`
3. bugs of `lexical_cast` or `iterator_range`
4. some other reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is number 2 from your list, misuse of `iterator_range` - specifically you're using it without explicitly including the proper header for it.

Adding this:

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
```

will make it behave as you expect.

The `iterator_range` and related functionality is split into two headers, `iterator_range_core.hpp` and `iterator_range_io.hpp`. The first one contains the class definition, the second one contains, among other things, the `operator<<` overload which makes it streamable and so usable by `lexical_cast` (usable in the sense that it will actually work as you expect).

Because you didn't included the proper header, you should normally get a compiler error, but in this case you're not getting it because `lexical_cast.hpp` includes the first of those two headers, `iterator_range_core.hpp`. This makes everything build fine, but it doesn't get the `operator<<` from the second header. Without that overload, when `lexical_cast` writes the range to the stream to perform the conversion, the best overload it finds is the one taking a `bool` parameter (because `iterator_range` has a default conversion to `bool`). That's why you're seeing that `1`, because it's actually writing `true` to the underlying conversion stream.

You can test this easily with something like this:

```
auto someRange = boost::make_iterator_range(first, last);
std::cout << std::boolalpha<< someRange;
```

Without `#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>` this will print `true`, with that `include` it will print your string (80).

Comment: This is such a serious fuckup that it is not even believable! Ended up system thinking that invalid number of consequent operations was constantly "1", while it was "2"! Luckily our unit tests revealed that something doesn't add up.


Beware, this is still happening on Boost 71 + Clang!